# Giving different colours to two different polygon symbols in same shape layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, layers

I made a new shapefile and then in ArcMap, with editor, made a new polygon and gave it a color by clicking the little color square in the Table of contents(TOC). Later on I saw that I needed to make another symbol inside the polygon I drew. So I drew a small circle inside the polygon(still using editor under the same layer). But I wanted the circle to be a different colour than the polygon. But I can't seem to find a way to change its colour (I don't want to have to create a separate shapefile).

I clicked the 'construct polygon' button to give the circle a solid colour since I don't want it to just be a circular ring inside my polygon. I tried playing around with some of the options under the symbology tab but no luck. And I can't seem to understand the solutions posted by other people in other forums.

The small islands in the picture are not drawn by me but are part of another shapefile.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unless i missunderstand your question you need to set symbology to Categories - Unique values and select a Value Field that is unique, for example shape area, objectID or whatever:

[image]

Or add your own field to use as Value Field. Add new field, right click Layer - Edit features - Start Editing and add your values in table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I found that it doesn't really help. As an experiment, I opened a new blank map and imported a shapefile of a city. Then I created a new polygon shapefile with arccatalogue and put in into my data frame. Then with the editor tool I made two polygons, one a triangle shape and one circle shape. Then I tried to change the colour of the circle to make it different from the triangle. When I tried to select a Value field that was unique, I found there was only one options to choose from which was Id. How do I then change the colour for these two features if there is only one?

Comment: For example add a new field and add text/values to and use as Value Field

Comment: Sorry, can you be a little more clear about your steps? You did not give steps like when adding a field, what I should select for the 'Type', etc

Comment: Type doesnt really matter. You need to start using the help sections of ArcMap: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/arcgis-field-data-types.htm

Answer (score 0):

1) [Add new field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/adding-fields.htm) on your table has long integer named **ID**.

2) Use [field calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm) ID = **[OBJECTID]**

3) [Create symbologie](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/drawing-a-layer-using-categories.htm) on your layer use unique values on field **ID**

You can also [peraring your map for editing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing/preparing-a-map-for-editing.htm) with specif value "categorie" *colors*
Add in your feature templates all colors you want and set color symbol correspoding to color name value.

field name = color
edit 
**Note**:

- ObjectID field is not visible in field list when you want create a symbology.
- Symbologie can add same color because it depends to number of unique color in color ramp and number of unique id in table
- Field name ID is an exemple and you can choose other name
- Field shape_area or shape_length is good but OID is better or use calculate index function.